# 2020-07-29T07:44:29.817503Z 108716 [Note] Aborted connection 108716 to db:

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, connectivity, connections, percona-server

We are getting continuously logs in mysql error logs

> 2020-07-29T07:46:56.534666Z 111536 [Note] Aborted connection 111536 to db: '' user: '' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)

we are using the following

```
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | ON       |
| interactive_timeout         | 1800     |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 1800     |
| net_write_timeout           | 1800     |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 60       |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout    | 60       |
| wait_timeout                | 1800     |
+-----------------------------+----------+
```

we are using percona MySQL server 5.7.30-33

let us know what we are missing or what we can do to resolve the issue.

I have referred some online topics with same errors but nothing resolved the issue

Thanks

Comment: Increase the timeouts massively

Comment: Looks like network connectivity problems.

Comment: we are using aws infra and vpc  network where both client machine & db server reside.     I have tested connectivity and privileges with mysql client and connection done without any issue. let us know which timeouts we should increase

Comment: does reverse dns resolution work? do you have skip-name-resolve in your configuration? Are user definations hostname based?

Comment: yes we have skip-name-resolve in config and user definations are IP based so any impact of skip name-resolve

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com ! Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @ Wilson Hauck config of db : 16 GB ,4 Core,SSD and config details and request details  you can check through                                                                                           https://pastebin.com/Z8Lsxw9F
https://pastebin.com/v9varR27
https://pastebin.com/PuiLqgSK

Comment: On a BUSY working day, Please post to pastebin.com A) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 30 minutes later B) another SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and C) last 400 lines of your error log and D) first page of either TOP or HTOP (or similar) for additional analysis.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry for the late reply A) https://pastebin.com/xrmQJVMT B) https://pastebin.com/aVqxsBQc and C) https://pastebin.com/1neKG667